# Auto open vimwiki when vim start

Tags: vim

I'm using vimwiki's managing todo-list feature as task management tool. So I edit the todo.wiki file frequently.

Everytime when I starting the todo list, I must type some command to open vim.exe(I use Launchy indeed), while the vim started,and then type \ww or :VimwikiIndex, I am tired of this way.

Is there any method that can auto load todo list when I want to ?I mean sometimes I just want to start vim for coding,and I have try the config below in .vimrc

```
autocmd VimEnter * VimwikiIndex
```

but vim open the todo-list everytime.So I want something like starting argument etc

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When you start your coding sessions by passing file(s) to Vim, you could check for that:

```
autocmd VimEnter * if argc() == 0 | execute 'VimwikiIndex' | endif
```

Alternatively, you could pass a dummy file `wiki` to Vim, and open the Wiki on that trigger:

```
autocmd VimEnter * if argv() ==# ['wiki'] | execute 'VimwikiIndex' | endif
```

But I would probably solve this outside of Vim through shell aliases

```
alias vimwiki='vim -c VimwikiIndex'
```

or a small `vimwiki` wrapper batch file on Windows

```
@vim -c VimwikiIndex %*
```

Comment: How is the third method works? How to write the .bat file? And I pasted second method's code into the .vimrc file, it occurs error.

Comment: You should include the error; otherwise, I can only guess. I've wrapped the `VimwikiIndex` command in `:execute`; plugins often forget the `-bar` definition. And I added the batch wrapper, but dude, this is really simple stuff.

Comment: sorry, because the error was reported in Chinese,so I didn't include it. But after you added `:execute` in the line , no errors any more!

Comment: Honestly, I'm a noob on programming batch files.I'll try to learn from now on.Thanks!